# Converting a Float32Array of decoded samples to an AudioBuffer

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api, aurora.js

Because one of the browsers I'm trying to support doesn't allow me to decode a specific codec using [`AudioContext.decodeAudioData()`](http://docs.webplatform.org/wiki/apis/webaudio/AudioContext/decodeAudioData) I'm using [Aurora.js](https://github.com/audiocogs/aurora.js) to decode a audio files.

How can I change the decoded samples received from Aurora.js into an AudioBuffer I can actually use to playback the audio?

This is my code so far:

```
var AudioContext = (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext);
var context = new AudioContext();
var segmentUrls = [
    '/segments/00.wav',
    '/segments/05.wav',
    '/segments/10.wav',
    '/segments/15.wav',
    '/segments/20.wav',
    '/segments/25.wav',
    '/segments/30.wav',
    '/segments/35.wav',
    '/segments/40.wav',
    '/segments/45.wav',
    '/segments/50.wav',
    '/segments/55.wav'
];

Promise.all(segmentUrls.map(loadSound))
    .then(function(buffers) {
        var startAt = 0;
        buffers.forEach(function(buffer) {
            playSound(startAt, buffer);
            startAt += buffer.duration;
        });
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
        console.error(err);
    });

function playSound(offset, buffer) {
    var source = context.createBufferSource();
    source.buffer = buffer;
    source.connect(context.destination);
    source.start(offset);
}

function loadSound(url) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
        request.open('GET', url, true);
        request.responseType = 'arraybuffer';

        request.onload = function onLoad() {
            resolve(decodeAudioData(request.response));
        };

        request.onerror = function onError() {
            reject('Could not request file');
        };
        request.send();
    });
}

function decodeAudioData(audioData) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var asset = AV.Asset.fromBuffer(audioData);
        asset.decodeToBuffer(function(buffer) {
            // Create an AudioBuffer here
        });
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to create an AudioBuffer of the appropriate size and # of channels, and copy the data from one Float32 buffer to another.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the MDN code snippet to put data in an AudioBuffer and then play it:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBuffer

```
// Stereo
var channels = 2;

// Create an empty two second stereo buffer at the
// sample rate of the AudioContext
var audioCtx = new (window.AudioContext || window.webkitAudioContext)();    
var frameCount = audioCtx.sampleRate * 2.0;

var myArrayBuffer = audioCtx.createBuffer(channels, frameCount, audioCtx.sampleRate);

button.onclick = function() {
  // Fill the buffer with white noise;
  // just random values between -1.0 and 1.0
  for (var channel = 0; channel < channels; channel++) {
    // This gives us the actual array that contains the data
    var nowBuffering = myArrayBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
    for (var i = 0; i < frameCount; i++) {
      // Math.random() is in [0; 1.0]
      // audio needs to be in [-1.0; 1.0]
      nowBuffering[i] = Math.random() * 2 - 1;
    }
  }

  // Get an AudioBufferSourceNode.
  // This is the AudioNode to use when we want to play an AudioBuffer
  var source = audioCtx.createBufferSource();

  // set the buffer in the AudioBufferSourceNode
  source.buffer = myArrayBuffer;

  // connect the AudioBufferSourceNode to the
  // destination so we can hear the sound
  source.connect(audioCtx.destination);

  // start the source playing
  source.start();

}
```

Comment: Despite what this code snippet (from MDN) appears to do, for some reason audio only comes out of the right speaker on Firefox (tested 54.0.1).  (Chrome and Edge are fine)

Comment: where will I put my Float32Array object in this snippet? Let's say I have an object named **floatObj** of type Float32Array which I wanna palce in **source.buffer**

Comment: @AliSajid did you ever figure this out? I'm trying to do the exact same thing

Comment: @JamesP I couldn't. I was converting my buffer to Float32Array, which didn't work so I just added Wav header in that buffer and assigned it to source.buffer